# PaintEventArgs e.Graphics only taking into account the on-screen coordinates for a scrollable control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a WinForms application (.NET Framework) considering a theme of whiteboard. I am drawing the lines using Graphics under the `Panel.Paint()` method.I am storing these lines data using a list so whenever a new line is drawn on the panel it triggers the `Paint()` function for the panel which iterates through the list of lines and redraw all the lines again on the panel.

The issue I am facing is when I scroll the Panel control in the application and try to draw a new line on the panel, the Graphics under the `Paint()` method is only considering the onscreen area of the control for drawing which is making the lines I have drawn on the panel previously to appear in the scrolled panel area which should not be the case as they were drawn up in the panel control.

Is there a way that under the `Panel.Paint()` method the Graphics would consider not only the area available on the screen but the size of the panel? So, that upon scrolling the panel all the lines drawn should not slide down with the panel and should also be drawn in the area of the panel not shown on the screen(up in the panel if the panel is scrolled down).

I have tried using the `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform()` and `e.Graphics.setClip()` but no luck so far. It would be nice if someone have a solution to it.

Here is the replica for the problem I am having in my project, Once the form is resized the scrollbars are added to it and upon scrolling the the lines are sliding down which should not be the case.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Point Start;
    Point End;
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
    List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Panel.AutoScroll = true;
        this.Panel.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(800, 500);
        this.Panel.Paint += Panel_Paint;
        this.Panel.MouseDown += Panel_MouseDown;
        this.Panel.MouseUp += Panel_MouseUp;
    }

    private void Panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        End = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        Line line = new Line(Start, End);
        lines.Add(line);

        Panel.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        Start = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void Panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        foreach (Line l in lines)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, l.Start, l.End);
        }
    }
}

internal class Line
{
    //Few properties for lines
    public Point Start;
    public Point End;

    public Line(Point start, Point end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you'd want to draw a line that cannot be visible is extremely unclear.  Do post the code that doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: Taking the example of the paint application in windows if I draw a line on it and then scroll down using the vertical scrollbar the line I have drawn will not appear on the visible screen area now, as it was drawn in the upper part of the canvas, but in my case once I scroll down, the line I drew again appears on the visible area as the Paint() function is invoked which takes in to consideration only the visible screen area and draw all the lines again in this area only. What I want is instead of `clipRectangle` being only the visible area for the `Paint()` method it should be the Panel size.

Comment: Your Line class should have an `Offset` property (of Type `Size`) that you set, when the canvas scrolls, to `new Size([Canvas].AutoScrollPosition)`. Then the drawing method becomes `e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, Point.Add(l.Start, l.Offset), Point.Add(l.End, l.Offset));` -- You class should probably expose a `Draw(Graphics g, Pen pen)` method, so in the Paint handler you can write `l.Draw(e.Graphics, p);`. The class method is then `g.DrawLine(pen, Point.Add(Start, Offset), Point.Add(End, Offset));` -- Note that you should use all floating point (`PointF` / `SizeF`) measures.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for this solution I have tried it but unfortunately not working under my scenario. Since I am also drawing the lines at runtime therefore the offset manages the lines which were present before scrolling but once I add a line after scrolling then due to the offset (`AutoScrollPosition` being  a negative value) the line is appearing on the coordinates above the points where I actually drew the line.

Comment: Of course you have to consider the Offset also when you add a new Line object. For example, in MouseDown you write `var offset = (sender as Panel).AutoScrollPosition; Start = new Point(e.X - offset.X, e.Y - offset.Y);`, ~the same in `MouseUp`. You're missing `MouseMove`, which is used to draw the temporary line while you move the Mouse Pointer (when `e. Button == MouseButtons.Left`)

Comment: Thank you @Jimi yes consideration of the Offset while adding the line objects worked for me.